# MariaDB 10.9: GRANT command syntax ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: sql, mariadb

Trying to create a limited backup user by running this command

```
GRANT SELECT, RELOAD, FILE, SUPER, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW ON 'db_prod'.* TO 'backup'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

I get error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''db_prod'.* TO 'backup'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' at line 1
```

I don't understand why

Comment: Remove the ingle quotes around `'db_prod'.*`, or use back-quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use single quotes around the database name, as this must be a database object and not a string

so write them with out single quotes or use backticks

```
GRANT SELECT, RELOAD, FILE, SUPER, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW ON `db_prod`.* TO 'backup'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but then I get `ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES`